# How to express custom Data in angular html file

Tags: html, angular, data-binding

Follwing example,

```
  <tr *ngFor="let participant of allParticipants">


          <td class="participant-properties">{{participant.orgId}}</td>

          <td class="participant-properties">{{participant.orgName}}</td>

          <td class="participant-properties">{{participant.address}}</td>

          <td class="participant-properties">{{participant.contactAdress}}</td>

          <td class="participant-properties">{{participant.homepage}}</td>

         <td class="participant-properties">{{participant.discription}}</td>

        <td class="participant-properties">{{participant.requestResumeList}}</td>


</tr>
```

> RequestResume[] requestResumeList

I want to express member field named 'resumeDetails' in participant.requestResumeList's single object

requestResumeList is RequestResume Array Type Object

```
   export class RequestResume {
      userId: string;
      requestDetails: string;
      user: User;
      requestResumeAssetId: string;
   }
```

I attempt

```
<td class="participant-properties">{{ participant.requestResumeList[1].resumeDetails }}</td>
```

but it's Failed

How to express resumeDetails field in angular html page

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I want to appear to participant.requestResumeList[1].resumeDetails on web page

Comment: To @Kamil Kiełczewski



Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "td". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("="participant-properties">{{ participant.requestResumeList[1].resumeDetails }}</td>
                [ERROR ->]</td>

              
"): ng:///AppModule/OrganizationComponent.html@295:16

Comment: can we have a sample value for `participant.requestResumeList[1].resumeDetails`? is there HTML code inside? does a `console.log` show the expected value?

Comment: @abc, Do you want to add a `property` called `resumeDetails` to `requestResumeList`? and can `RequestResume` class be changed?

Comment: @Kaddath
Yes, participant.requestResumeList is exist. 
participant.requestResumeList is appeared to [object Object]
but console log is not appeared in console.log in <script> tag.

Comment: @Basavaraj Bhusani, No, RequestResume[] requestResumeList and resumeDetails is defined in RequestResume

Comment: @abc , `resumeDetails` is not defined in `RequestResume`, as `RequestResume` is a class like this ->    `export class RequestResume {
      userId: string;
      requestDetails: string;
      user: User;
      requestResumeAssetId: string;
   }`

Comment: @abc in case you can't find what's wrong following Basavaraj Bhusani's comment: `resumeDetails` is different from `requestDetails`, you are calling the wrong property

Comment: Oh, My mistake.

Comment: Thank everyone.
resumeDetails-> requestDetails
this problem is solved